# Bash quotes being tricky

Tags: bash

I have this command

```
aws --profile whatever ec2 describe-instances
```

The short story is that I no choice but to have this '--profile ' section in this command, but I need to be able to use this feature/bug using quotes:

```
aws --profile "" ec2 describe-instances
```

BUT the quotes must also be an environment variable, like so

```
aws --profile $AWS_PROFILE ec2 describe-instances
```

But I need that variable to resolve the exact same way as the line above it.
I have tried

```
AWS_PROFILE='""'
```

and

```
AWS_PROFILE=
```

and

```
AWS_PROFILE=""
```

And it never resolves the same way. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: BashFAQ #50 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- is your friend.

Answer (score 4):

Any quotes you put inside the variable are *literal*. However, in your desired command `aws --profile "" ec2 describe-instances`, the quotes are *syntactic*: That is, they're *shell syntax* describing how the shell is going to create a literal array of C strings to pass to the `execv` syscall (and how one of those strings needs to be empty); the quotation marks aren't actually passed to the `aws` command themselves.

So:

```
AWS_PROFILE=
aws --profile "$AWS_PROFILE" ec2 describe-instances
```

...will behave identically to

```
aws --profile "" ec2 describe-instances
```

Comment: Compare the behavior of the two commands with `set -x` (to log everything the shell runs to stderr) preceding them.

Comment: Woops sorry for the pithy reply. Enter doesn't behave how I expected. Trying out the 'set -x' thing now

Comment: It resolves to aws --profile '' ec2 describe-instances. Single quotes.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Your initial explanation works fine if the variable is anything but AWS_PROFILE. I've moved past a bash problem into an AWS problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @techgnosis, ...the thing to keep in mind about quotes, there, is that they're syntactic -- `''` and `""` mean the exact same thing to an application, since they both mean that the argument passed is an empty string.

Comment: @techgnosis, ...but, yes, it's very possible that the application is paying attention to that variable directly, if it's exported in the environment. Does `declare -p AWS_PROFILE` shows `declare -x AWS_PROFILE="something"`, or `declare -- AWS_PROFILE="something"`? If it's the former, then it's in the environment, and applications you run can read its value directly.